Single-spa navigation between micro-frontends
I have a single-spa application that consists in a root-config app that targets two micro-frontends which are react.js applications, each app including the root-config are hosted in a github repo respectivly.
The issue is that when I try to navigate between micro-frontends using navigation links this modify the URL by removing the root path /root-mfe so it ends up like /mfe1 and if the page is refresh it returns a 404 because the URL is wrong. Adding # in the path doesn't help because it doesn't load the targeted micro-frontend.
These are the main files of the root-config app:
index.ejs:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Root Config</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/regenerator-runtime@0.13.7/runtime.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https: localhost:*; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: localhost:*; connect-src https: localhost:* ws://localhost:*; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https:; object-src 'none';">
  <meta name="importmap-type" content="systemjs-importmap" />

  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
        "react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js",
        "react-dom": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
        "single-spa-react": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa-react@4.6.0/lib/system/single-spa-react.min.js",
        "@guille/root-config": "https://guille-gallo.github.io/root-mfe/guille-root-config.js",
        "@guille/mfe": "https://guille-gallo.github.io/news-reader-mfe/guille-mfe.js",
        "@guille/bookstore-mfe": "https://guille-gallo.github.io/bookstore-mfe/bookstore-mfe.js"
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/import-map-overrides@2.2.0/dist/import-map-overrides.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs@6.8.3/dist/system.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/systemjs@6.8.3/dist/extras/amd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <script>
    
  System.resolve = System.constructor.prototype.resolve;

  System.constructor.prototype.resolve = function () {
    const url = System.resolve.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log(`SystemJS is resolving ${arguments[0]} to ${url}`);
    return url;
  };

  System.import('@guille/root-config').then(() => {
    console.log('Root config loaded');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error loading root config:', err);
  });

  window.addEventListener('single-spa:before-routing-event', (event) => {
    console.log('Routing event:', event);
  });

  </script>
  <import-map-overrides-full show-when-local-storage="devtools" dev-libs></import-map-overrides-full>
</body>
</html>

microfrontend-layout.html:
<single-spa-router>
  <main>
    <nav>
      <div><a href="/hacker-news" onclick="singleSpaNavigate(event)">hacker news</a></div>
      <div><a href="/books-store" onclick="singleSpaNavigate(event)">books store</a></div>
    </nav>
    <route default>
      <application name="@guille/mfe"></application>
    </route>
    <route path="/hacker-news">
      <application name="@guille/mfe"></application>
    </route>
    <route path="/books-store">
      <application name="@guille/bookstore-mfe"></application>
    </route>
  </main>
</single-spa-router>

guille-root-config.ts:
import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";
import {
  constructApplications,
  constructRoutes,
  constructLayoutEngine,
} from "single-spa-layout";
import microfrontendLayout from "./microfrontend-layout.html";

const routes = constructRoutes(microfrontendLayout);
const applications = constructApplications({
  routes,
  loadApp({ name }) {
    console.log(`Loading app: ${name}`);
    return System.import(name);
  },
});
const layoutEngine = constructLayoutEngine({ routes, applications });
console.log("ROUTES -> ", routes)
applications.forEach((app) => {
  console.log(`Registering application: ${app.name}`);
  registerApplication(app);
});

layoutEngine.activate();

start();
console.log('Single-SPA started');

So how can I navigate between these micro-frontends with navigation links?.
Thanks for any help!!

Are you communicating your routers that they have a base path they need to respect?  I don't do React, so don't ask me how, but generally speaking you have routes that look like "/mfe1/featureA" and the like.  You're missing the base "/root-mfe".

The routing in this case is handled by single-spa framework, if you check microfrontend-layout.html the routes are defined there and the targeted micro-frontend is loaded by singleSpaNavigate(). So the issue resides in how single-spa handles the routing, locally all works correctly but I guess this has something to do with Github Pages as well...

Ok, but link generation (for  components) need to know the base.

Yeah good point, I've now implemented a mfe for the navbar with BrowserRouter and the links components like <Link to="root-mfe/hacker-news" It now loads the targeted mfe correctly but if the page is refreshed then the mfe url path is removed and the root-mfe is loaded again, there's probably a way to handle this so working on that now
